# DateTime set to an hour earlier

Tags: apex, datetime, time, businesshours

I have an object of type Time startWorkingTime and object of type DateTime nextBusinessDay. I want to create new object of type DateTime based on startWorkingTime  and nextBusinessDay.
Here is my code:

```
DateTime startWorkingTime = DateTime.newInstance(nextBusinessDay.year(), nextBusinessDay.month(), nextBusinessDay.day(), currentStartHours.hour(), currentStartHours.minute(), currentStartHours.second());
```

After startworkingtime the time is set one hour earlier

For example in bold:

> 23:59:24:025 USER_DEBUG [188]|DEBUG|currentStartHours 09:00:00.000Z
>   23:59:24:025 USER_DEBUG [189]|DEBUG|currentStartHours.hour() 9
>   23:59:24:025 USER_DEBUG [197]|DEBUG|startWorkingTime 2017-08-04 **08**:00:00

Could you please explain why the hour in startWorkingTime is **08**:00:00 and advise how to fix it?

Comment: What's your time zone? Did you try `Datetime.newInstanceGmt`?

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Datetime.newInstanceGmt helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Datetime.newInstanceGmt` instead.

```
Datetime instance = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```